# How to unite path without redrawing in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, performance, paperjs

Paper.js have methods to unite paths in this way

```
const result = circle1.unite(circle2).unite(circle3)
```

but to render result I need to remove it from canvas, and draw it again

```
if (result) {
  result.remove();
}

result.strokeColor = new Color("red");
```

it leads to poor performance, is there way to optimize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent the [View](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/) from redrawing automatically everytime you perform an action, you need to set [`view.autoUpdate = false`](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#autoupdate). This means that you need to control the redraw manually by calling [`view.update()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#update) when you want a redraw to take place.

From then on, you can also perform boolean operations without inserting the result in the Scene Graph, by passing `insert:false` in the options object which is the 2nd argument to [`Path.unite`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#unite-path):

```
paper.view.autoUpdate = false

const circle1 = new paper.Path.Circle({
    position: new Point(100, 60),
    radius: 50,
    strokeColor: 'black'
})

const circle2 = new paper.Path.Circle({
    position: new Point(150, 60),
    radius: 50,
    strokeColor: 'black'
})

const circle3 = new paper.Path.Circle({
    position: new Point(200, 60),
    radius: 50,
    strokeColor: 'black'
})

const result = circle1
    .unite(circle2, { insert: false })
    .unite(circle3, { insert: false })
    
paper.view.update()

console.log(result)
```